# html show parent div on center of child div having height greater than child

Tags: html, css

I have a div like:

```
<div style="background-color: blue; height: 10px">
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 10px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I have a div that containers a div which height is double to its parent div.

The child is displayed with height double to its parent, but its extra 10px height is displayed at bottom.

What I want it if parent div is 10px and child div is 20px, child should show extra 10px equally on bottom and top, like parent is on centered.

What is the proper way of doing this ?

Comment: 'position' is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You could use position aboslute, and then minus half the height of the parent:

```
<div style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width:100px">
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 100px; background-color: green; opacity: 0.5; position: absolute; top:-50px">
    </div>
</div>
```

See codepen here: http://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/qRQdyP

Answer (score 0):

The code posted below with no absolute positioning works as well.

```css
.parent {
 background-color: blue; 
 height: 10px;
}

.child {
 height: 20px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```